# type definition for third party class

Tags: typescript

i have a third party library called canJS.
there is this [can.Map](https://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.html) module. this module is written in AMD. you can load that with a dependency loader e.g. requirejs.

with can.Map we provide 2 ways for create an instance.

1. `let foo = new can.Map([props])`
2. `let Foo = can.Map.extend([name,] [staticProperties,] instanceProperties);
   let foobar = new Foo();`

i tried to write a simple type definition for this class

```
declare module "can/map/" {
  class canMap {
  }
}
```

but now i stuck.

how look that kind of type defintion.
i always get an error like this:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or
>   construct signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use appropriate [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html) to write a declaration file.

In your case, I think, it will be something like this:

```
declare module can {
  class Map {
    constructor(props: any);
    static extend(name, staticProperties, instanceProperties): Map;
    attr(): {[index: string]: any};

    // Declarations for other properties and functions
  }
}
```

usage (of course, "canjs" should be loaded):

```
var a = new can.Map({});
var b = can.Map.extend({}, {}, {});
var c = a.attr();
```

#### Update 1

The best way is find definitely typed declaration on [definitelytyped.org](http://definitelytyped.org/). Almost all popular libraries definitions already have been written.

You can use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) for "d.ts" files management.

#### Update 2

Optional arguments ("?" marked) and static function "extend" returns a constructor (with overload):

```
declare module can {
  class Map {
    constructor(props?: any);
    static extend(instanceProperties): { new(): Map };
    static extend(name, staticProperties, instanceProperties): { new(): Map };
    attr(): {[index: string]: any};

    // Declarations for other properties and functions
  }
}

let creator1 = can.Map.extend({});
let creator2 = can.Map.extend({}, {}, {});
var c = new creator1();
```

Of course, you should specify type of function arguments (now thay are of "any" type).
You can find more details in Typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).

Comment: Also, make sure to check out the [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) project as there might already be type definitions available for the plugin/framework you're using.

Comment: @TedNyberg - you right, man. The first thing I've done - I've checked "tsd" and "typings" repos. But with no succes for "canjs" and "can.js" names (https://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.html#section_Use). May be it has another name?

Comment: i am a contributor for canjs, currently we have no definitions. i would like to write some...

Comment: This explains typescript definition absence. Hope my answer will help you.

Comment: i will check this late and give you a feedback, thanks

Comment: @TSV your provided definition works fine for `let foobar = new can.Map();` but it will not work for `let Foo = can.Map.extend({}); let foobar = new Foo();` i got an error: `TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`
`can.Map.extend()` return a new extended constructor function. your static extend definition return a instance of `Map` why is this not working?

Comment: This is because I've given you a sample definition. If you want to declare optional arguments, you can use "?" sign, e.g. "constructor(props?: any);" and "static extend(name, staticProperties?, instanceProperties?): Map;" Other error you have got because I don't know details of implementation of your library - I've updated the answer.

Comment: @TSV the problem was not the missing arguments. the problem was the missing `{ new(): Map }`. why do we need to return a new Map? in your first anwser you defined a return type of Map. `static extend(name, staticProperties, instanceProperties): Map;` why is that not enough?

Comment: If function returns object of Map type, this means you will get an instance of Map. If function returns { new(): Map }, this means you will get constructor function, which you can call later to obtain an instance of Map. "new ()" means constructor for Map.